# Sequential workflow adding another copy of item on update of list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, sequential-workflow

I have created a custom Sequential workflow in which i am assigning task to user like :

```
private void createTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item; 
       RequestApproveTaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
       RequestTaskProperties.Title = "";
       RequestTaskProperties.Description = "Please review the request";
       RequestTaskProperties.StartDate = DateTime.Today;            
       RequestTaskProperties.AssignedTo = userName;            
       RequestTaskProperties.EmailBody = this.EmailBody;
       RequestTaskProperties.HasCustomEmailBody = true;
       RequestTaskProperties.SendEmailNotification = true;
    }
```

its creating task properly and assigning to user. No issue, working fine. 
and I have set workflow start when adding new item to the list.

**Problem** *comes when I edit/update the List item value on which workflow is running and is in process. Insted of updating the existing item, It add one more item in the library with updated value which again run workflow on newly added list item.*

So, My Question is how to stop this get added new item with updated value.I want to update the existing list Item and hit the **OnChange()** function of Sequential Workflow. Please respond I am not getting solution on Google.

Comment: I solved it. There are OntaskChange() and OnWorkflowItemChange() activity, first get fired when u edit the task and second get fired when you edit the List/Library associated with workflow.

Answer (score 1):

ItemAdding Workflow executed every time when you add anything in your list item. Try to write you code in **ItemAdded**. Then your code runs properly as you wish.